# GCC fails compiling anything (even an empty file) with error: 'pthread_mutex_timedlock' was not declared in this scope

Tags: gcc

I recently installed GCC and CYGWIN. Every time I try to build anything (even and empty file) I get the following message.

> "\usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\7.3.0\include\c++\x86_64-pc-
>   cygwin\bits\gthr-default.h||In function 'int 
>   __gthread_mutex_timedlock(__pthread_mutex_t**, 
>   const __gthread_time_t*)':| \usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-
>   cygwin\7.3.0\include\c++\x86_64-pc-cygwin\bits\gthr-default.h
>   |768|error: 'pthread_mutex_timedlock' was not declared in 
>   this scope| \usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\7.3.0\include\
>   c++\x86_64-pc-cygwin\bits\gthr-default.h|768|
>   note: suggested alternative: '__gthread_mutex_timedlock'|
>   ||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))."

There is a related thread at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53238 but it has been  dormant for years and didn't solve the problem.

Does anyone know of a workaround or fix?

Comment: Can you provide the compilation command you're using?

Comment: Did you install gcc as a part of cygwin or separately?

Comment: I installed it as part of Cygwin. I've tried a few different command line options, but nothing made a difference. I'm using codeblocks, which issues: gcc.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g -Wall -pthread  -c . I added the -Wall and -pthread at some point but have since removed them, so I don't know where they are coming from. My last compile was with no options except those codeblocks generates.  I'll try compiling from the command line to see what happens,

Comment: GCC seems to work from the command line, and that's good enough for me right now.